# Is it possible to resurrect Ellie?

Tags: dex

In the comments of [this Steam guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=468087611), Spirit_OK on 8 Jul, 2020 @ 4:07pm said:

> I did 4->1 with Ellie, she left, there indeed was a body near Mitchell, but I believed that was a "yesterday's break in" from the security emails. Later in after-game Ellie was alive in her apartment, and there was a choice to tell her about Iain if met earlier.

A.k.a:

> Ellie was given the footage of Iain, then she confronted Michell and died because of it, but was seen alive after.

Is that possible still? Or might it depend on if Mitchell was also shown his POW massacre footage, because that's an unmentioned variable.